# Can I play Windows games through virtual desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, windows, steam, playonlinux

I've tried playing Windows steam games through PlayOnLinux, and it just glitches and closes. Everybody on the forums says that it worked, and it doesn't. Is it possible to play steam games through a virtual desktop? I.E. VMWare?

Comment: Some games work, however some games just don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it can be super laggy depending on the computer, and the game. Windows really is a big OS and could crash your hardware. Virtualbox and or VMware might work great depending on the game though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, or I should say if you want to play it on extremely low FPS!

Also most of the stuff you do on virtual machines drastically increases load on your processor, ie. gaming might cause high CPU load and the VM might crash. If the games are old then you can try, and you might get some playable performance.